# Reinstalling an Nvidia driver

Tags: drivers, nvidia

I recently purchased a Ubuntu computer from Dell with an NVIDIA Quadro P4000, 8GB, 4 DP (5820T) graphics card.

When I upgrade the kernel will I have to reinstall a driver for the card?

Comment: It depends on a lot of things: Ubuntu version, how you installed Nvidia drivers, what do you mean by "upgrade the kernel"

Comment: no you should be fine